# Can you use a large file directory of jpgs for without georeferencing

Tags: geoserver, raster, georeferencing, jpg, slippy

I have a large map data set of 256x256 jpg images. The file directory is organized by /map_type/zoom/x/y.jpg. I have 12 zoom levels and each zoom level directory has 2^(2*zoom level) images.

I have been researching how to display map data using GeoServer and almost everything I have read says that I need to georeference the images. This would not be practical with the methods I've seen because I have such a large data set.

Is there a way to display the map data based on the file location? I found a similar tile structure on wiki called [Slippy Maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) but after skimming through it, it sounds like they convert vector data to tiles. All of this is kind of confusing to me. Some clarification on how map data is created and served up would be very appreciated.

Comment: create world files jpgw for each jpg. http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/jpgw a simple batch can be create for all your images. [correction .jgw for geoserver]

Comment: Are thes files some sort of tiles? You could serve them as WMTS service/tiles if you know the rest of the configuration.

Comment: The files are just jpg's. for example, at zoom 0 the directory would be /maps/terrain/0/00000/00000.jpg

Comment: @Mapperz, thanks for the info. After I create all of the .jpgw files, how would I tell GeoServer to use the entire file directory instead of one individual file?

Comment: individual files required - in Geoserver this is called WorldImage - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/worldimage.html

Comment: @Mapperz If I added each file I would have over 22 million different stores on GeoServer and then I would have to make layer groups based on the zoom level. Is there a way to configure the world files to work together instead of individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am **answering** this question based on the assumption that you have a Disk Cache of Tiles, with tiles (in jpeg format) arranged by a standard XYZ grid.

If this is the case, then you do not need Geoserver to serve these tiles. You just need to place them in a location which is accesible to your web server.

You need to know the projection and location of the images.

You can then use [OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ-js.html) to display these tiles in your OpenLayers Application.
Here is an [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mapquest.html) of how tiles can be directly accessed and shown in a map.

You should also have a look at [Using Custom Tile Sources / Google-like Tile Layer Support](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles)